# Does IPv4 of all devices follow this standard xxx.xxx.x.x?

Tags: ipv4, networking

I think the title says it all. I haven't found the answer anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: Sadly, this question shows little or no research.  For example, you might look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) .

Comment: An IPv4 address is an unsigned, 32-bit number. There are various notations, more or less human-readable.

Comment: This is just a common way to represent IP addresses that are just a 32-bit unsigned integer. People find it easier to remember 10.0.0.1 rather than 167,772,161 or 0x0A000001. Another layer on top of that is DNS that converts these numbers to meaningful names - e.g. www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IPv4 address is an unsigned, 32-bit number. For human readability, it is most often written as four decimal octets, separated by dots, e.g. `192.0.2.253`. Any octet can range from 0 to 255 (2<sup>8</sup>-1). Not all combinations represent valid IP addresses.

IPv6 uses 128-bit addresses that are most commonly written as eight 16-bit hexadecimal words (each 0 through ffff), separated by colons. Multiple, consecutive 0 words including their colons can be abbreviated by :: a single time, e.g. `2001:0db8:85a3::0370:7334` for `2001:0db8:85a3:0:0:0:0370:7334`.